# Regex remove the first charcter from the group - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have long string and I want to split the string to sentences.
To do it, I need to use Regex.

This is my regex:

```
([A-Z1-9]{1}.+?\.)\s*[A-Z1-9]{1}
```

(every sentences start with capital letter and end with `.` and then I check if the first letter after the dot has capital letter or a number).

when I run the following  python code:

```
    txt = """ DETROIT—Alter Road runs northwest along this city’s border. To the east is Grosse 
           Pointe Park, an upscale suburb dotted with grand old mansions built in the auto industry’s 
           heyday. To the west is the city of Detroit, lined with abandoned houses and empty lots.
           On the east side of the street, getting a mortgage to buy a home is a breeze. On the west 
           side, it is hardly worth trying.

           Detroit is making a comeback after years of decline that led to a bankruptcy filing in 
          2013. But large swaths of the city are left behind, starved of the housing credit needed to 
          revive them. No purchase mortgages were made last year in almost a third of Detroit’s 
          census tracts, and fewer than five each in another third, according to data from 
          LendingPatterns.com, a mortgage-data analysis tool. """

     r1 = re.findall(r"([A-Z1-9]{1}.+?\.)\s*[A-Z|1-9]", txt, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
     print(r1)
```

im getting :

[image]

The first letter of each sentences is down, and I dont understand why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need `re.findall(r'[A-Z0-9].*?\.(?=\s*(?:[A-Z0-9]|$))', text, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookahead instead to do the check and omit the capture group as you want the match only.

You can omit `{1}` and as there is a space at the end of the text, you can assert either `\s*[A-Z1-9]` or `\s*$` to also match the last line.

```
[A-Z1-9].+?\.(?=\s*(?:[A-Z1-9]|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sFM6U4/1)